# Finding a specific multivariable derivative in jax

Tags: python, jax

The code below allows me to get the partial derivative with respect to the three inputs of some function of the array x

```py
import jax.numpy as jnp
import jax

def f(x):
    return jnp.prod(x)

x=jnp.array([1.0,2.0,3.0])

funs = [f]
funs.append(lambda x: jax.grad(funs[0])(x)[0])
funs.append(lambda x: jax.grad(funs[1])(x)[1])
funs.append(lambda x: jax.grad(funs[2])(x)[2])

print(funs[3](x))
```

I would like the code above to generalize to an arbitrary number of inputs (and for some more complicated functions) thus I try:

```py
funs = [f]
for i in range(n):
    z = lambda x: jax.grad(funs[i])(x)[i]
    funs.append(z)

funs[3](x)
```

but now I get the following error

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_331066/1225421420.py in <module>
     19     funs.append(z)
     20 
---> 21 funs[3](x)

/tmp/ipykernel_331066/1225421420.py in <lambda>(x)
     16 funs = [f]
     17 for i in range(n):
---> 18     z = lambda x: jax.grad(funs[i])(x)[i]
     19     funs.append(z)
     20 

    [... skipping hidden 10 frame]

... last 11 frames repeated, from the frame below ...

/tmp/ipykernel_331066/1225421420.py in <lambda>(x)
     16 funs = [f]
     17 for i in range(n):
---> 18     z = lambda x: jax.grad(funs[i])(x)[i]
     19     funs.append(z)
     20 

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Any idea how to make this work for any number of variables?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `i` is a global variable, so it takes the value when the function is called, not when the function is defined. If you want the local value of `i` when the function is defined to be saved, you have to somehow bind it to the function; for example:

```py
funs = [f]
for i in range(n):
    z = lambda x, i=i: jax.grad(funs[i])(x)[i]
    funs.append(z)

funs[3](x)
```

The result you're seeing is not anything specific to JAX, but rather comes from how Python variable binding works: when global variables are referenced in functions, the relevant value is not the value when the function is defined, but the value when the function is called. For example:

```py
>>> funs = []
>>> for i in range(3):
...   funs.append(lambda: print(i))
>>> print(i)
2
>>> funs[0]()
2
>>> funs[1]()
2
>>> i = 100
>>> funs[0]()
100
```

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot. Is this explained somewhere in the docs of Jax?

Comment: No, this isn’t really a JAX-specific thing, it’s how variable scope works in Python in general.